# Jfrog artifactory OSS port 8046 go away after sometime

Tags: artifactory

We recently installed artifactory 7.6.1. Installation went fine and we are able to access the console and work on it but after sometime of not being used jfrog artifactory doesn't respond on browser and we realized port 8046 went away which was active when jfrog started initially. below is the error

```
2020-07-16T07:33:00.111Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [8a0affa9a62fb8a2] [o.j.a.c.h.AccessHttpClient:130] [art-exec-6          ] - Error while executing /api/v1/users/ on access.
 Exception message: Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2020-07-16T07:33:00.119Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [8a0affa9a62fb8a2] [o.a.m.s.CallHomeService:118   ] [art-exec-6          ] - Failed calling home: Unable to connect to Acces
s server: Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientException: Unable to connect to Access server: Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connec
tion refused)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.restCall(AccessHttpClient.java:136)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBaseImpl.makeRequestAndParseResponse(AccessClientBaseImpl.java:163)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBaseImpl.findAll(AccessClientBaseImpl.java:110)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBaseImpl.findAll(AccessClientBaseImpl.java:99)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.user.UsersClientImpl.findUsers(UsersClientImpl.java:60)
        at org.artifactory.storage.db.security.service.access.AccessUserGroupStoreService.getAllUsersInternal(AccessUserGroupStoreService.java:304)
        at org.artifactory.storage.db.security.service.access.AccessUserGroupStoreService.getAllUsers(AccessUserGroupStoreService.java:271)
        at org.artifactory.storage.db.security.service.access.AccessUserGroupStoreService.getAllUsers(AccessUserGroupStoreService.java:267)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy178.getAllUsers(Unknown Source)
        at org.artifactory.security.SecurityServiceImpl.getAllUsers(SecurityServiceImpl.java:778)
        at org.artifactory.security.SecurityServiceImpl.getAllUsers(SecurityServiceImpl.java:773)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy172.getAllUsers(Unknown Source)
        at org.artifactory.metrics.providers.features.SecurityFeature.addUsers(SecurityFeature.java:143)
        at org.artifactory.metrics.providers.features.SecurityFeature.getFeature(SecurityFeature.java:65)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
        at org.artifactory.metrics.services.CallHomeService.addFeatures(CallHomeService.java:188)
        at org.artifactory.metrics.services.CallHomeService.callHomeEntity(CallHomeService.java:163)
        at org.artifactory.metrics.services.CallHomeService.callHome(CallHomeService.java:111)
       at org.artifactory.metrics.services.CallHomeService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1d14b447.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.artifactory.schedule.aop.TraceableMethodInvocation.proceed(TraceableMethodInvocation.java:72)
        at org.artifactory.schedule.aop.AsyncAdvice.doInvoke(AsyncAdvice.java:333)
        at org.artifactory.schedule.aop.AsyncAdvice.lambda$submit$2(AsyncAdvice.java:285)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.artifactory.opentracing.TraceableRunnableDecorator.run(TraceableRunnableDecorator.java:30)
        at org.artifactory.concurrent.ArtifactoryRunnable.run(ArtifactoryRunnable.java:53)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
        at org.jfrog.client.http.CloseableHttpClientDecorator.doExecute(CloseableHttpClientDecorator.java:109)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.restCall(AccessHttpClient.java:123)
        ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        ... 61 common frames omitted
```

I tried to google but I was not really successful in finding a solution. Please suggest. thanks !

Here is the log from Access-log, looks like its not able to load Master.key but there is file present in the location

2020-07-14T02:04:30.745Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [7f37937aee67c266] [a.k.m.MasterKeyBootstrapper:70] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - No master.key supplied. Generating master.key
2020-07-14T02:04:30.842Z [jfac ] [ERROR] [7f37937aee67c266] [.k.m.MasterKeyBootstrapper:122] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Found existing master key fingerprint in the D
B, without master.key file. Please provide a master key file manually in '/opt/app/jfrog/current/var/etc/security/master.key'.
2020-07-14T02:04:30.842Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [7f37937aee67c266] [.k.m.MasterKeyBootstrapper:125] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Waiting for 1 minute until the key is supplied
manually...
2020-07-14T02:04:35.846Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [7f37937aee67c266] [o.j.s.c.KeyUtils:108          ] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Master key is missing. Pending for 5 seconds w
ith 60 seconds timeout
2020-07-14T02:04:40.847Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [7f37937aee67c266] [o.j.s.c.KeyUtils:108          ] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Master key is missing. Pending for 5 seconds w
ith 60 seconds timeout
2020-07-14T02:04:45.851Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [7f37937aee67c266] [o.j.s.c.KeyUtils:108          ] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Master key is missing. Pending for 5 seconds w
ith 60 seconds timeout

Comment: Restart the service

Comment: sure I did that but after sometime the access service port 8046 is going away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably know the Artifactory server is a combination of Artifactory + Access services. The log snippet you have shared indicates the inability of not connecting to the service running on port 8046 i.e access service. It looks like the Access service is went down for some unknown reason. The best place to look for the reason behind this failure is access-service.log which is generally located under /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log. It might be helpful if you can share the snippets from this file

Comment: Hi Prasad I added the log snippet above and its missing master.key

Comment: Hi Vamsi, I dont think the missing master key is causing the issue as you mentioned it as a fresh install, Artifactory would create the master.key. The reason could be something else. Check for stack traces in acce-service.log or console.log for any evidence.
Also can you make sure the port 8046 is not blocked by any firewall

Comment: It turns out to be nessus scan which is crashing jf-router service. we did correct it and we dont have issues. Thanks for your help Prasad.

Comment: @LakshmiPrasad are you sure that port 8046 is used for access service ? I read it is defaut port for router (I dont understand the router thing at the moment though)